VerifyTests: ‘TestContext' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
We recently started to use VerifyTests/Verify on Mstest .Net 8. Projects.
One of my colleagues has an error on local build:

CS0119  'TestContext' is a type, which is not valid in the given
context

when accessing the TestContext property in a class like
[TestClass]
    [UsesVerify]
    public partial class ItineraryAttachmentTests
    {
        private async Task<string?> Test( )
        {
           return await DebugSaveAndViewModelAsHtml( TestContext);
        }
}

The error doesn’t happen on other developers machines.
On the GitHub Actions build server the normal build/tests run correctly.
But CodeQL analyser reports the same error:

We were unable to automatically build your code. Please replace the call to the autobuild action with your custom build steps. Encountered a fatal error while running "/opt/hostedtoolcache/CodeQL/2.20.0/x64/codeql/csharp/tools/autobuild.sh". Exit code was 1 and last log line was: Error: Could not auto-detect a suitable build method. See the logs for more details.
error CS0119: 'TestContext' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

The build compiler correctly understands that 'TestContext' is a property , implemented in auto-generated partial class , but  the analyser doesn’t see the generated class .
Do you have any suggestions, how to avoid the error?
How can we somehow troubleshoot or enforce src/Verify.MSTest.SourceGenerator, if it doesn’t work?
The functionality of the  SourceGenerator described in Use attribute instead of base class for MSTest #1193
It is expected that file like the following will be generated:
C:\Users\Michael.Freidgeim\AppData\Local\Temp\VSGeneratedDocuments\cc80ecff-236e-87d6-92d8-0d293fe16153\UsesVerify.g.cs
namespace UnitTests
{
    partial class ItineraryAttachmentTests
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Verify.MSTest.SourceGenerator", "1.0.0.0")]
        public global::Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext TestContext
        {
            get => global::VerifyMSTest.Verifier.CurrentTestContext.Value!.TestContext;
            set => global::VerifyMSTest.Verifier.CurrentTestContext.Value = new global::VerifyMSTest.TestExecutionContext(value, GetType());
        }
    }
}


I’ve noticed the warning, that explains the issue

CSC : warning CS9057: The analyzer assembly
'/home/runner/.nuget/packages/verify.mstest/28.2.0/analyzers/dotnet/roslyn4.4/cs/Verify.MSTest.SourceGenerator.dll' references version '4.9.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the
currently running version '4.8.0.0'.

My colleague fixed the issue by upgrading to the latest version of Visual Studio.
I've asked a question on VerifyTests is it possible to downgrade compiler
To enforce latest version of Roslyn in CodeQL I found the recommendation (not tried yet):
https://github.com/github/codeql-action/issues/757#issuecomment-977459242

you can add the following to your .yml file as one of the steps in the
job. I added this just before the "Initialize CodeQL" step.

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: '8.x'

